# How to install and work with npm when linking app source in docker-composer?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

The installation of `node_modules` passes without errors.

Running `docker-compose run --rm npm run dev` empty `app.js` also does not output errors, everything compiles normally.

If I import it to the `app.js` empty `App.vue` there are no errors, and if I add  tags or other html-tags, I get an error:

```
glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
}

ERROR in ./resources/js/components/App.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|  <div class="container">
| 

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I install `npm` in **docker-compose.xml** without dockerfile:

```
npm:
    image: node:latest
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']
    networks:
      - laravel
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "npm": "^7.7.5",
        "zlib": "^1.0.5"
    }
}
```

Tell me, how is it correct?

Comment: This isn't about npm, the error is coming from webpack. You can see at the end of "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type..."  that it's giving you a link to webpack's documentation.

Comment: This setup doesn't really seem to be making use of the Docker ecosystem at all.  If you just run `npm install` on the host without Docker, do you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

You linked your app source in volumes section but you didn't include the node_modules. I had the same problem when i first deploy my Node project to Docker too.

To fix the problem, link your node_modules aswell.

If you want to name that volume, create a volume in Docker and link your node_modules to that volume. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/

```
volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www/html
    - my_node_volume:/var/www/html/node_modules
```

Or just link without spesifying and it will auto generate that volume for you.

```
volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www/html
    - /var/www/html/node_modules
```

I'm adding a small example about how i used it.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    my-app:
        image: eagleclaw/my-app
        container_name: my-app
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        volumes:
            - /home/eagleclaw/my-app/app:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
        command: ["npm", "start"]
        restart: unless-stopped
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./app/ .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
```

setup.sh

```
DOCKER_FILE="/home/eagleclaw/my-app/docker-compose.yml"
APP_DIR="/home/eagleclaw/my-app/app"

docker build --no-cache -f $APP_DIR/Dockerfile -t eagleclaw/my-app $APP_DIR

docker-compose -f $DOCKER_FILE -p app up -d
```

When i have this sources, i can simply go to my sh folder and run it and it will generate Docker image and deploy it to a Docker container.

And in my Node project i'm listening on `IP 0.0.0.0` and `PORT 3000`.

Comment: `could not find expected ':'`  auto generate don't work

Comment: Sorry, my bad. If you want to auto-generate you should use `- /var/www/html/node_modules`. That `:` should be removed if a volume isnt specified.

Comment: Also edited the answer. Can you please try again?

Comment: `sh: 1: mix: not found` and if I write `- ./ path/to/project/node_modules:/var/www/html/node_modules` then nothing changes, the original error

Comment: I added an example of usage. I'm using this example on my projects and it works for me. If it still fails after doing this, i'm unable to help you about. Hope it works, good luck.